# Not able to install MI package in R

Tags: linux, r, ubuntu

```
ERROR: dependency ‘Rcpp’ is not available for package ‘minqa’
* removing ‘/home/vivek/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15/minqa’
ERROR: dependency ‘Rcpp’ is not available for package ‘RcppEigen’
* removing ‘/home/vivek/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15/RcppEigen’
ERROR: dependency ‘pbkrtest’ is not available for package ‘car’
* removing ‘/home/vivek/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15/car’
ERROR: dependencies ‘Rcpp’, ‘minqa’ are not available for package ‘lme4’
* removing ‘/home/vivek/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15/lme4’
ERROR: dependencies ‘arm’, ‘car’, ‘lme4’ are not available for package ‘mi’
* removing ‘/home/vivek/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15/mi’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmpu1TVD3/downloaded_packages’
```

I get the above error when I try to install package for Multiple Imputation in R. I have used following command to install the package on R console.

```
install.packages('mi')
```

Comment: You need all the listed packages to be first installed. Try with `install.packages("Rcpp", dependencies = TRUE)`, then `install.packages('mi', dependencies = TRUE)`. Also, I would **highly** recommend you to upgrade your version of R first.

Comment: Pascal- sorry, i get the same error

Comment: I am using ubuntu 12.10

Comment: @Pascal Warning message:
package ‘Rcpp’ is not available (for R version 2.15.1)

Comment: That is why I recommended you to upgrade R first. You version is almost 3 years old. And current version of package `Rcpp` depends on R (≥ 3.0.0).